# Change Div Css on document scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to div position to be fixed when document scroll and that div reached to 50px from top.

Please check the code below

HTML

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="nav"></div>
<div id="left"></div>

<div id="right">
    <div id="box1"></div>
    <div id="box2"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#main{ overflow:hidden; width:600px; height:900px; background:#afaaac; margin:0; padding:0; }

#nav{ width:600px; height:40px; background:#15bc44; position:fixed; margin:0; padding:0;}

#left{ overflow:hidden; width:400px; height:900px; background:#18769e; float:left; }

#right{ overflow:hidden; width:200px; height:900px; background:#bc1544; float:right; }

#box1{ float:right; width:150px; height:200px; display:block;background:#e34d2a; margin-bottom:20px; }

#box2{ float:right; width:150px; height:200px; display:block;background:#e34d2a; margin-bottom:20px; }

.box2{ position:fixed; margin-left:50px; margin-top:50px; }
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var s = $("#box2");
    var pos = s.position();                   
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var windowpos = $(window).scrollTop() ;
        //s.html("Distance from top:" + pos.top + "<br />Scroll position: " + windowpos);
        if (windowpos >= pos.top) {
            s.addClass("box2");
        } else {
            s.removeClass("box2");
        }
    });

});
```

This work but it will go to the top of the document and jump back 50px.

I also tried changing

`$(window).scroll(function() {` to

```
$(window).scroll(function() > 50 {
```

and

`if (windowpos >= pos.top) {` to `if (windowpos >= 50) {`

This all seems make position jump around. Please check the JSFiddle below

http://jsfiddle.net/uGw2Z/2/

If anyone can point me out the correct way to do this, i will really appropriate it.

Comment: Output like this : http://jsfiddle.net/uGw2Z/3/ ?

Comment: @Zword Thank you this works great. if you can add this as an answer i can select as the correct answer for others to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a number inorder to remove jump : 
`windowpos+54`

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uGw2Z/3/)

Comment: Awesome. Work like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the css code in the `.box2` like this:

```
.box2{position:fixed; top:50px; margin-left:50px}
```

check out this fiddle : [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tejashsoni111/uGw2Z/5/)